# Inserir hífen ("traço" -) automaticamente enquanto usuário digita

Tags: java, android

Há alguma forma de enquanto o usuário digitar num `EditText` ir inserindo hífen (-) a cada 4 caracteres digitados? Da mesma maneira como funcionam algumas licenças o traço (-) já é inserido automaticamente.

Comment: Você pode usar esse plugin https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText, vai facilitar muito.

Comment: Achei mais fácil @EduardoSilva mas deu um erro na hora de compilar o app. Não lembro extamente qual era mas dizia algo de que não tinha `Mask` no plugin indicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um tutorial legal e funciona em tempo de execução [aqui](https://andremrezende.wordpress.com/tag/android-mask-mascara-edittext-java-layout-cpf-cnpj/):

É só trocar Mask.insert("###.###.###-##", cpf) pela mascara que tu quer.

Comment: Poderia postar um exemplo aplicando isto no Android? Aplicando em um componente *swing* não faz muito sentido pela pergunta do AP.

Comment: Tá um pouco complexo, mas foi o melhor que consegui

Comment: Obrigada @PauloCosta resolveu!!